# Google geocoding api search with Arabic language address

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am passing arabic lang search text in Google geocoding api query, but returns no result in json

string strResult="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=جدة  +السليمانية "&sensor=false&language=ar";

gives

{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}

kindly suggest the correctway of passing arabiclanguage search text in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must encode the address-part, it should be:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A9+%2B%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9+%22&sensor=false&language=ar
```

How to encode it depends on the used programming-language

Comment: i m using c# lanugage,                                        String TestString = cityname + "+" + distname;
        String EncodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);      still no result.

Comment: I guess it must be [Server.URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  (I'm not familiar with C#)