# How to geocode arabic locations in R

Tags: r, api, google-maps, geocoding, arabic

This question has been answered in a different context ([Google geocoding api search with Arabic language address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122668/google-geocoding-api-search-with-arabic-language-address)), but the answer does not work in R.

I have a column of arabic locations in R that will successfully return a location on the general google maps website. For example,

The location: الكلاكلة صنقعت

will successfully find a location on google maps (https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A9+%D8%B5%D9%86%D9%82%D8%B9%D8%AA%D8%8C+Khartoum,+Sudan%E2%80%AD/@15.4627489,32.4903488,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x168e8488cc997c1f:0x8ebb3396724dd0d5!8m2!3d15.4624516!4d32.4948384).

However, because of the nature of the reported location (usually neighbourhoods / localities), point location reporting is not usually available. Does anyone know a workaround **in R using the ggmap package?** I am open python solutions, but i have little experience outside R and Python.

Will try to provide more information - apologies for gaps as this is my first question.

Comment: What's the issue? `ggmap::geocode(location = "الكلاكلة صنقعت")` works...

Comment: Huh weird that is working for me but wasn't working when doing only geocode(LOCATION). I'll play around a bit more and get back to you but so far that seems to work!